# SQL Server Filtering Index performance

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Currently have an index like;

```
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CDPAYAPP_INDEX03] ON [dbo].[CDPAYAPP]
(
    [CLSVC_ID] ASC,
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90)
```

Unfortunately, at some of our clients the value for CLSVC_ID can be zero for 100k or more of rows out of a couple million total rows.  This cardinality appears to cause the optimizer to occasionally consider the index less than optimal, resulting in table scans.  Updating stats multiple times a day can help but not always.

I tried to apply a FILTERING INDEX clause, like;

```
create UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED index CDPAYAPP_INDEX3A ON CDPAYAPP (CLSVC_ID, ID)
WHERE CLSVC_ID > 0;
```

But noticed that if I requested any column outside the two index columns it uses the original index not the filtered index.  If I only select the columns of the index, it uses the filtered index.

Why?

Comment: Can you give us the query to optimize with its query plan ? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior, described by you, occurs because the query optimizer chooses the most efficient index based on the columns, involved in the query. When selecting only columns in the filtered index, the index is covering, making it more attractive to the optimizer.

However, when selecting additional columns, the index is no longer covering, leading the optimizer to choose a different index or perform a table scan. To encourage the use of the filtered index, you can include additional columns using the INCLUDE clause, making the index covering for more scenarios.

The example index could be:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX CDPAYAPP_INDEX3A ON CDPAYAPP (CLSVC_ID, ID)
INCLUDE (AdditionalColumn1, AdditionalColumn2)
WHERE CLSVC_ID > 0;
```